# using the standard Communities page without header

Tags: visualforce, community, iframe

I'm planning to have a customer facing communities page (with login performed via SSO) embedded as an iframe within an existing website. As such, I can get the user straight to the "Communities" page and displaying all the content I need.

The problem I have, is that since the existing website already has headers/styling that doesn't match the communities interface, I want to switch it all off. Essentially I want just the stuff in the div class zen-main. I'm happy with the functionality aside from that so don't necessarily need to build a customer page.

What is the best approach to take for this? Should I build a visualforce page? I've taken at look at this, but can't work out which components I need to include, and reading the guide it references compnents like:

Can anybody point me in the right direction as to where to start, as I'm fairly need to salesforce and am finding the options & choices quite bewildering.

Is it possible to have the default communities "tabbed" container, but with custom css to hide the stuff I'm not interested in seeing?
Is it possible to havea  visualforce page with the header/sidebar switched off, but then include a "communities" object? (wihtout having to completely rebuild the community interface with other components)>